# Retrieve all states along route using HERE or Google Maps APIs

Tags: google-maps, here-api, directions

I am developing a resource that requires us to know all states along a route that is provided from HERE or Google Maps. I attempted to pull the leg/step data from both APIs, but those steps sometimes do not include all the states.

i.e. if the route is from Los Angeles, CA to Albuquerque, NM, we need to extract the states California, Arizona, and New Mexico.

Answer (score 0):

Within the HERE Routing API you retrieve easily this information by adding a so called summaryByCountry parameter. Here is an example request:

Example Request for SummaryByCountry:

https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.xml
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&waypoint0=geo!50.8857,14.81589
&waypoint1=geo!50.8681536,14.8308207
&routeattributes=wp,sm,sh,sc
&mode=fastest;car

Example Response for SummaryByCountry

```
<Route>
. . .
<Summary>
<Distance>2218</Distance>
<TrafficTime>109</TrafficTime>
<BaseTime>109</BaseTime>
<Flags>motorway</Flags>
<TravelTime>109</TravelTime>
</Summary>
<SummaryByCountry>
<Distance>297</Distance>
<TrafficTime>21</TrafficTime>
<BaseTime>21</BaseTime>
<Flags>motorway</Flags>
<TravelTime>21</TravelTime>
<Country>DEU</Country>
</SummaryByCountry>
<SummaryByCountry>
<Distance>1471</Distance>
<TrafficTime>58</TrafficTime>
<BaseTime>58</BaseTime>
<Flags>motorway</Flags>
<TravelTime>58</TravelTime>
<Country>POL</Country>
</SummaryByCountry>
<SummaryByCountry>
<Distance>450</Distance>
<TrafficTime>30</TrafficTime>
<BaseTime>30</BaseTime>
<Flags>motorway</Flags>
<TravelTime>30</TravelTime>
<Country>CZE</Country>
</SummaryByCountry>
</Route>
```

More details can be found here:  https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-route-representation-options.html

Comment: Thank you, that provided the exact information I needed.